# What permission set allows a user to be able to save a field mapping?

Tags: export, advanced-search, field-mapping

Drupal 7 - Civi 5.45.7
In the past users have been able to create new field mappings (from the Advanced Search screen). Now I can't seem to find a way to allow them to do that without granting "CiviCRM: administer CiviCRM". Am I just overlooking something? Is there a way to grant average users the ability to create and update field mappings?

Comment: My question is very similar, but I'm coming from a participant search. The users are given the option to save the field mapping, but when they press the save button they just get a spinning wheel against the button which keeps going. Is that what you get or is this just something similar. If it won't do it, it ought to say so! I certainly don't want to use what is an "allow everything" permission.

Comment: Ours is on contact and case searches (we don't have the events module on) the option is missing altogether - the admin role can see the "Save Fields" button at the bottom of the list of fields for export but non-admin users cannot.

Comment: So my problem is a bit different and I have now asked a separate question https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/45026/problem-saving-field-mappings-for-export

Answer (score 0):

At some point it became a javascript form and it says `<span ng-if="data.columns.length && perms.admin">`, so it means "administer CiviCRM".

See https://github.com/civicrm/civicrm-core/blob/097b4785cff256c7d46bb8ca8b394ed0d7483040/ang/exportui/export.html#L22

and

https://github.com/civicrm/civicrm-core/blob/097b4785cff256c7d46bb8ca8b394ed0d7483040/ang/exportui/exportui.js#L28

Comment: mmhh, I have users who do not have this permission ("administer CiviCRM") but the "Save field" button shows up.

Answer (score 0):

This option was initially not permissioned which [caused errors](https://github.com/civicrm/civicrm-core/pull/19733) for some users who could access but not save field mappings. Now it is [well-aligned](https://github.com/civicrm/civicrm-core/pull/26262) for those who can an export can also save a mapping since version 5.63.