# Problem saving field mappings for export

Tags: field-mapping

As a CiviCRM admin, I have no problem saving field mappings for export, but it isn't working properly for non-admins. I can't see any permissions that might be missing (I don't want to give them full admin permissions). The problem showed up with exporting participants, but the problem is also there for contacts. All works fine up to the actual save but it then hangs with a spinning wheel on the final save button. I thought it might be the same as [What permission set allows a user to be able to save a field mapping?](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/42881/what-permission-set-allows-a-user-to-be-able-to-save-a-field-mapping) but the symptons are different there in that they cannot see the save option at all.

Using CiviCRM 5.35.1 on WordPress.

Comment: When you Export, and when Non-Admins do an Export - are you both choosing specific fields,  or are you both using Primary Fields - or are you doing the former and they doing the latter? if the last option then i have a suggestion

Comment: Both chosing specific fields and I don't see how you would get an option to save mappings if you were just using primary fields.

Comment: sorry yep read it too quickly and was thinking about the problems folk have had using Primary Fields in exports. you are right.

Answer (score 0):

I think this [was fixed](https://github.com/civicrm/civicrm-core/pull/26262) a couple weeks ago. Can you test it on master?

Comment: Happy to try but don't know what "master" is. But, also, the fix seems to refer to the other similar question, where the "save fields" button is missing. I have that, but it gets stuck later. But maybe this is because I have quite an old version of CiviCRM

Comment: Do you have a test site that you could try the very latest code for CiviCRM on (master)? Normally you could just check something like this on the demo site (https://dmaster.demo.civicrm.org/), but I don't think you'll be able to set up the permissions you need there. In any case, if it is now working in the most up to date version, I'd assume the fix will be to update your site when 5.63 comes out.